# How can I show users that an element is a 3d model that can be rotated?

Tags: navigation, web

I have an important element on my website that can be 3d rotated if the user clicks or touch and drag to the sides. When running a few tests with people, I noticed they skip it through it and never rotate the object.

How could I make it so that they know that the object rotates while still keeping a clean look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always add a semi-transparent 3d rotation indicator icon on top of the element that fades when the user touches the image.

The icon indicates the possibility to interact and the fading the beginning of the action.

[image]

Comment: Nice, I like this solution

Answer (score 0):

Might be a idea to rotate the Model upon arriving on the page indicating it's an model instead of just a background. Making it spin for a second